# Oracle AQ - how to determine if a listener is listening to the queue

Tags: jms, mule, oracle-aq

If I have an AQ set up, but my listener (Mule JMS endpoint) is not receiving any messages. Is there a view that I can query to determine what listeners Oracle thinks are connected to the queue?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://wedostreams.blogspot.ca/2009/01/oracle-aq-buffered-queues-101.html:

> You can check queue subscribers by querying the AQ$MYQUEUE_TABLE_S view (or AQ$_MYQUEUE_TABLE_S table) like below:

```
col name    format a12
col address format a40

select name, address
from aq$myqueue_table_s
where queue='MYQUEUE';

NAME      ADDRESS
------------ -------------------------
SUBSCRIBER1
SUBSCRIBER2
```